# Easypermission, the permission native dialog is coming by itself, I didn't execute any function

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, adb, android-native-library

The easypermission is implemented in my app. The behaviour of showing the permission native dialog is on click. In Android 11 and greater the flow is working as it's implemented.

But in Android 10 or less, when the user comes to home screen after the splash screen. The permission dialog automatically occurs. I have searched all the code but no where can find the source of any EasyPermissions.requestPermissions.

How to fix this I can't get any source of the issue to fix.

Comment: You seem to refer to the "easypermission" library, but there is link to the project, so it is not 100% clear what you mean by "easypermission". Please always include a link to the external resource when it is important for your question.

Comment: ok I'll keep this in check for the next time. Yes the EasyPermission library I'm referencing to. Well I fixed this issue.
Thankyou by the way.